# Local wordpress dev issue index.php and admin work - no other pages respond

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, osx-mavericks

I am having a severe issues setting up a local dev environment on my mac for a wordpress site i am working on. Below is the process i have tried:

Start apache locally
Set up dev environment in httpd.conf files
Set up dev name.
Set up dev name to link to location of files
Set up dev IP.
This process worked fore every other instance except this one.

The wp-admin works fine and all posts and updates can be made there. The index.php works fine. However, this is it. No posts are working and they all come back with the same error message: 'The requested URL // was not found on this server’.

*It should be mentioned that I had xampp installed on my machine and it was running out of the same port as my local apache and sql. I changed the ports on xampp and this did not work. I uninstalled xampp, restarted my computer and this did not work.

I have several other virtual environments up and they work just fine – though they are not .php and sql based. I have been looking into this issue for about a day now and cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X by default disables `.htaccess` overriding in order to enable it follow these steps:

Open this file:

```
/etc/httpd/users/yourusername.conf
```

Save with:

```
<Directory "/Users/yourusername/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache with this command:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: How do I access the file in the first step? My permissions do not allow me to update the file directly and I each time i unlock and change permissions, they revert back. How would i get there from the terminal?



Edit -**Figured out how to gain access**